# MetaSearch undefined method 'all' in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm hoping to search Users in my Rails 3 app with MetaSearch. However when I start off following Railscast 251, I'm already getting an undefined method 'all' in my UsersController index action. Here's that code:

```
def index
  @search = User.search(params[:search])
  @users = @search.all
end
```

The start of my form:

```
<% form_for :search, @search, :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :high_school_contains %>
  <%= f.text_field :high_school_contains %><br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In Gemfile:

```
gem 'meta_search'
```

Both Ryan and [Ernie Miller](http://erniemiller.org/2010/03/07/metasearch-object-based-searching-for-rails-3/) recommend code along those lines in the index action, but something is obviously wrong. Any ideas on what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use other search solution like thinkingsphinx or define search method in model? if yes so it defines search method first and metasearch dont use it, source code:

```
alias_method :search, :metasearch unless respond_to?(:search)
```

so you just need to use metasearch method:

```
@search = User.metasearch(params[:search])
```

Comment: That returns a similar `undefined method 'relation'`

Comment: what is @search.class return? what is ruby version?